# how to rename sheets with macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, rename, macro-recorder

I want to create a macro in Google Spreadsheet which allows me to rename sheets with variable data.

First I've added a macro that duplicates my sheet 'BLANCO' 6 times, I works well.

I've created a sheet named DATA, in cells A1 to A6, I've added names. It works to rename the sheets to these names, but the macro uses the exact name and not the link to this cell.
For example:
DATA!A1 = Andreas
In stead of referring to DATA!A1, it reffers to the data in this cell. So if I change this name "Andreas" to "Aster", de macro will still use the initial name (Andreas).

Here's the script of the macro:
[image: printscreen]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Also, kindly include a sample spreadsheet and the desired output.

Comment: On this site code should be added as text, not as image, also when adding code it should be a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
function renameSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let resp = ui.prompt(`Current Sheet is ${sh.getName()} Enter new name or cancel`,ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(resp.getSelectedButton == ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL) {
    sh.setName(resp.getResponseText());
  }
}
```